# Json schema with keys as data

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have some hard time dealing with json schema.

Suppose this is initial simple json.

```
[
  {
    "Field1": 1,
    "Description": "Default"
  },
  {
    "Field1": 77,
    "Description": "NonDefault"
  }
]
```

And this is schema written which is valid

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "Field1": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "Description": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to change Json, to use "Field1" as key.
"Field1" is integer value.
I do not know values and how many Field1 there will be in json.

This is final JSON

```
{
    "1": {
        "Description": "Default"
    },
    "77": {
        "Description": "NonDefault"
    }
}
```

But how to write json-schema for this JSON?

Comment: how can you be sure that your keys are unique? are you going to check all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TimRoberts' answer is almost there.  What you want is to describe the item in the `patternProperties` subschema, similar to how you have `items` in your example schema.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^[0-9]*$": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Description": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "propertyNames" with a "pattern" element to create a regular expression to qualify your key names, instead of enumerating them all. I, personally, prefer your first layout.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^[0-9]*$": { "type": "string" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your schema still looks for an array.  OP is looking for an object in the end.

Comment: An excellent point.  I didn't look closely enough.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for answer but how to enforce that each element (for example "77")  has "Description" (type:string)?

Comment: OK, I just tweaked it.  I would like to point out that I had not encountered "JSON Schema" until an hour ago, and my answers came from reading the docs.  That's a hint to you.